# SessionScoped bean not being found in Quarkus service

Tags: cdi, quarkus

I have a Quarkus app that uses `cdi` and `resteasy`. I have a bean that is annotated as `SessionScoped`

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
@SessionScoped
public class SessionScopedBean implements Serializable {}
```

When I inject this bean into my web resource I get `javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException`:

```
@Path("/dep")
public class DependencyResource {

    private final SessionScopedBean ses;

    public DependencyResource(SessionScopedBean ses) {
        this.ses = ses;
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: 
Unsatisfied dependency for type SessionScopedBean and qualifiers [@Default]
        - java member: DependencyResource#<init>()
        - declared on CLASS bean [types=[DependencyResource], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=DependencyResource]
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.resolveInjectionPoint(Beans.java:472)
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.init(BeanInfo.java:404)
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:212)
```

If I change it to `ApplicationScoped` or `RequestScoped` it works without any other changes.

Do `SessionScoped` beans work with Quarkus 1.0.0.CR1?

Comment: Do you have the right sessionscoped annotation?

Comment: I'm using `import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;`

Comment: try injecting the service as:
 @Inject
 SessionScopedBean ses

Comment: @HectorVenturaReyes yes, I have tried it that way too. Same result.

Comment: I suspect things may have been updated since 2019-10-13  relevant docs at https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference and I just created a @SessionScoped bean without undertow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Quarkus, there is [`SessionContext`](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/extensions/undertow/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/undertow/runtime/HttpSessionContext.java) but it is wired directly into `Undertow` extension as opposed to request or application contexts which are part of Arc (Quarkus DI) that you get almost always as components require it.

Therefore, check that you have `undertow` extension enabled or try adding it manually and see it that helps.